# How to change MySQL checkpoint interval

Tags: mysql, performance, checkpoint

I've tried changing "progress status update interval" in MySQL Workbench but I'm not sure if the change happened. The interval that I've tried are 1, 4, 20, 200, and 400000.

However, the running time of this query doesn't change much under those different interval settings:

```
UPDATE trade SET quantity = quantity + 100;
```

Could anyone help me on change the checkpoint interval? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the MySQL's internal, but a checkpoint usually happens **after** a transaction. So I would be surprised if a single statement causes a checkpoint to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I've tried changing "progress status update interval" in MySQL
>   Workbench but I'm not sure if the change happened. The interval that
>   I've tried are 1, 4, 20, 200, and 400000.
>
> However, the running time of this query doesn't change much under
>   those different interval settings:"

These settings don't affect the running time of a query at all. They are parameters you might change if you have a long running query and a slow connection. But this parameter has nothing to do with how long your queries will actually take.

That being said, you might be able to speed up this query a bit using an index on your quantity variable. Alternatively, you might try chunking the table into pieces, eg,

```
UPDATE trade SET quantity = quantity + 100 WHERE trade.id BETWEEN 1 AND 10000;
UPDATE trade SET quantity = quantity + 100 WHERE trade.id BETWEEN 10001 AND 20000;
```

etc. But just changing progress status update interval in the Workbench... that's not gonna affect your query speed at all. Totally unrelated.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But chunking the table doesn't improve performance, especially when there's only one query at a time.